# Is there a statement which is $\alpha$-unprovable for all ordinals $\alpha$?

Tags: logic

Define $\alpha$-unprovability (relative to a fixed theory) - for $\alpha$ an ordinal - as follows:

- $p$ is $0$-unprovable iff $p$ is unprovable.
- $p$ is $\alpha$-unprovable for $\alpha>0$ if, whenever $\beta<\alpha$, the sentence "$p$ is $\beta$-unprovable" is unprovable.

Does every consistent theory to which Godel's incompleteness theorem applies contain a statement which is $\alpha$-unprovable for all ordinals $\alpha$?

Comment: The definition of $\alpha$-unprovable seems garbled ...

Comment: Fixed it. The first word should have been $\beta$-unprovable

Comment: I still don't think that's what you mean - how is $1$-unprovable different from $0$-unprovable?

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, I mean that $\beta$-unprovable *is unprovable* for all $\beta < \alpha$.

Comment: That's better, but the phrasing's a bit sloppy. Let me edit a bit to clarify, and let me know if I've gotten the wrong idea.

Answer (score 2):

There's an important subtlety here - we need to be able to express $\alpha$-unprovability in the language of our theory, so we're really talking about [ordinal *notations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_notation) instead of ordinals themselves. However, this isn't really an issue here:

---

The answer is **yes**, but for silly reasons. Remember that a "Godel-applicable" theory $T$ can *never* prove any sentence of the form "$T$ doesn't prove ---," since such a sentence implies the consistency of $T$.

Now suppose $p$ is **any sentence at all**. For *every* ordinal $\alpha$, the statement "$p$ is $\alpha$-unprovable" implies that *something* (not necessarily $p$ itself) is unprovable, and so for no ordinal $\alpha$ can "$p$ is $\alpha$-unprovable" be provable. That is:

> Every sentence is $\alpha$-unprovable for every $\alpha>0$.

(In particular, this doesn't fit the idea of what a hierarchy of unprovability should do.)

So now just take some $p$ which is $0$-unprovable.

Comment: But ZFC proves that CH is unprovable, so CH is $0$-unprovable, but not $1$-unprovable, right?

Comment: @Stefan No - ZFC proves that *if ZFC is consistent then* CH is unprovable. No (appropriate) theory ever literally proves that it doesn't prove something.